# How to fix Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Tags: java

Im on a mac and I am trying to "hack" minecraft. When I launch my hack client it says this:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:
>   net/minecraft/client/main/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:637)   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)   at
>   java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)

Ummm I tried using java 7 and 8. (Latest updates) But what do I do now? Im so confused because it wont launch. Please help. I love hacking <3

Comment: The version of java you are trying to use to run minecraft is too old. You might have Java 8 installed, but if you were really using Java 8 you wouldn't be getting this error.

Comment: Okay I used this link: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html
tell me if something is wrong please :D

Comment: Oh if I didnt do it right send me the real link please :P Sorry if I'm being mean i just wanna get this fixed...